# Jenkins (2.297) build fails because an "output.xml" file could not be parsed

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

i set up an Jenkins-> robot framework chain where the robot tasks are stimulated by Jenkins.
The example robot tasks (some simple shell scripts) are executed without errors, but Jenkind fails because it is not able to parse some "output.xml" file which has nothing to do with the robot framework tasks.
Error message:

```
[ ERROR ] Reading XML source '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/output.xml' failed:ParseError: junk after document element: line 188, column 0
```

When i investigate the "output.xml" there is indeed an error:

```
   ...
   rrors>
   </errors>
   </robot>
```

This behavior is already known and active and is described in https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-62359?attachmentViewMode=list

in 2020, but the error is still appearing.

Is there a solution or workaround? It is curious that sometimes the build is executing without an error when nothing changed.

Comment: The output.xml file format has changed a little recently. Are you certain you're using a version of the jenkins plugin compatible with the new format?

Comment: I use Jenkins as it was distributed. I did not changed anything.

Comment: Updated to Jenkins 2.301 where the release notes said that this error would be fixed, but still the same error.